# É possível serializar closures no PHP?

Tags: php, serialização, closures

É possível serializar closures no PHP (mesmo que não seja nativamente)?

Pois o PHP gera um `Fatal Error` ao tentar fazê-lo:

```
$func = function ($a, $b)
{   
     return $a + $b;
};

serialize($func);
```

Isso gera:

> Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Comment: Relacionado (SOen): http://stackoverflow.com/a/19730234/2256325

Comment: Útil: http://www.htmlist.com/development/extending-php-5-3-closures-with-serialization-and-reflection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja trazendo conteúdo do SO para cá. Então é só fazer o que já [foi respondido lá](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13734224/221800). A função `serialize()` não vai funcionar mesmo, ela não está preparada para isto.

Há uma outra solução postada lá que deve ajudar melhor o que quer, é o uso de a biblioteca [Super Closure](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) que usa reflexão para alcançar o objetivo. Se quiser fazer algo por conta própria, o melhor caminho é analisar o que esta biblioteca faz.